# Progressive web app on a wordpress installation

Tags: wordpress, progressive-web-apps

We now have a basic html site with a database including an admin panel to add new rows. This database can then be viewed on the website by visitors. We would like to convert the website to wordpress (because of its usability and blog-like structure), but also keep the database with its information.

I recently stumbled on the progressive web apps -- they offer some great features like offline usage. Can I deploy a pwa on a subdomain on my wordpress installation or would it be better to let someone write a wp-plugin for this? I guess it would be a pain to combine Javascript and Wordpress, but maybe there;s a simple solution for this.

Thank you,

Regards

Comment: Is this question still relevant? A very short answer is 'yes, a PWA on a subdomain is a good solution'. However, why not using your Wordpress install itself as a PWA?

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy PWA on a sub domain, the conditions for a PWA is the website should be responsive and HTTPS.

Already their is an awesome plugin that helps in converting a WordPress website into Progressive Web Apps called "Super Progressive Web Apps" Hope this plugin will be helpful for your need :)